# PCRE - Match each if and only if something much further ahead fits

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm struggling to solve this problem. I need to match each occurrence of `id` such that the next `array` must be empty (i.e. `[]`).

```
{
    "objs":[
        {
            "id":73642,
            "henro":null,
            "oo":0,
            "array":["boxed"],
            "hehe":"haha"
        },
        {
            "holy":"guacamole",
            "id":"pick me!",
            "henro":null,
            "meow":"rrrraawwrr",
            "oo":null,
            "array":[],
            "say":"what"
        },
        {
            "not id":null,
            "null":null,
            "id":"don't pick me",
            "henro":3781237,
            "2173881":"henro",
            "oo":"hehe",
            "array":["baz"]
        },
        {
            "id":"pick me 2!",
            "henro":null,
            "oo":0,
            "array":[],
            "ola":"elo"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Important Note

I've formatted the data just to make it readable. Please work on the compact version instead (hover over):

> `{"objs":[{"id":73642,"henro":null,"oo":0,"array":["boxed"],"hehe":"haha"},{"holy":"guacamole","id":"pick me!","henro":null,"meow":"rrrraawwrr","oo":null,"array":[],"say":"what"},{"not id":null,"null":null,"id":"don't pick me","henro":3781237,"2173881":"henro","oo":"hehe","array":["baz"]},{"id":"pick me 2!","henro":null,"oo":0,"array":[],"ola":"elo"}]}`

---

#### The Goal

Must match all values of `id` that are followed by `"array":[]`. Therefore, in the example, the only valid matches are `"pick me!"` and `"pick me 2!"`. Both must be matched (global mode).

---

#### Constraints

- There is always an `id` before an `array`.
- In between an `id` and the next `array`, there can be any number of `"attribute":<value>` pairs.
- The value of an `id` cannot be enclosed in `{}` or `[]`.
- The value of an `id` is guaranteed not to contain any `,` character. The `,` character at the end, e.g. `"id":73642,`, is not considered a part of the value as it serves as a delimiter.
- The regex must be PCRE only.
- This is not really a constraint, but I prefer a solution that can be confirmed [here](https://regex101.com/r/6D1ABB/1/).

---

#### My Attempt

`"id":([^,]+).*?"array":\[(?(?=])]|\K)`

I naively thought `\K` would also reset the capturing group, but it doesn't, because the regex [matches all](https://regex101.com/r/6D1ABB/1/) of the id's.

Comment: You might consider using something like `"id":(?|"([^"]+)"|(\w+))[^][]*?"array":\[]`, but it is still "fragile".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew At least it works!

Comment: It won't  if there is `[` or `]` between the id and `"array"`

Comment: True. I still wish I had thought of `[^][]*?`. That's nice.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into consideration all your constraints, the most approximate regular expression you might use is

```
"id":"([^,]+)[^][]*?"array":\[]
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L2M2Xo/2).

**Details**

- `"id":"` - a literal `"id":"` string
- `([^,]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than a comma
- `[^][]*?` - any 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]`, as few as possible
- `"array":\[]` - a literal `"array":[]` string.

Comment: I don't see a point in using the branch reset group, because `([^,]+)` is adequate due to the constraint that an `id` cannot contain any comma character. Anyway, I'll accept this approximate answer for now, as it is good enough for my use case, at least until the developers make some changes to the data and break the regex.

Comment: @NikoGambt The branch reset group is handy when you need to get the contents of the quoted part of a string without quotes, or if the value is composed solely of word chars.

Comment: The thing is the branch reset group will fail if there is an escaped double quote `\"` in between the opening and closing double quotes, and the second alternative cannot handle it either because double quote is not a word character. Of course, I didn't mention that in my constraints. So, it's not your fault.

Comment: @NikoGambt That is a long solved issue, replace `(?|"([^"]+)"|(\w+))` with `(?|"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|(\w+))` or `(?|"([^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*)"|(\w+))`

Comment: I still see no good value in using a different regex that's not `([^,]+)` given the explicitly stated constraint that the `id` is guaranteed to contain no commas at all.